# docker and couchbase sdk install

Tags: php, docker, couchbase

so i am trying to install couchbase php sdk on a php container on docker.
everything is fine but there is an error.
i have this as my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo
RUN pecl install --alldeps xdebug couchbase
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug libcouchbase couchbase

COPY docker/php-fpm/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini
```

and this is what happwns at the end:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.9.0
88 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20180731
Zend Module Api No:      20180731
Zend Extension Api No:   320180731
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserHHlcdZ/couchbase-2.6.1
running: /tmp/pear/temp/couchbase/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 1.1.1 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Couchbase support... yes, shared
checking wheter to use system FastLZ library... no
checking for libcouchbase in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcouchbase distribution -
                 libcouchbase.h should be <libcouchbase-dir>/include and
                 libcouchbase.a should be in <libcouchbase-dir>/lib
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/couchbase/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failed
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install --alldeps xdebug couchbase' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

the problem is with couchbase php extension. why is this happening?

i tried yo install it using apt-get but there are other errors that way.

Comment: Right before the two ERROR messages, there are some instructions about libcouchbase. Did you check those?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when installing couchbase PHP SDK on Apple M1 MacBook Air. I have installed `libcouchbase`:

```
brew install libcouchbase
```

I had to also install `pkg-config` which couchbase PHP SDK installer could use to resolve `libcouchbase` paths:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

After that, php SDK installer was not throwing `libcouchbase in default path... not found` errors

```
pecl install https://packages.couchbase.com/clients/php/couchbase-3.1.1.tgz
```

but compile was failing at later stage. I have figured out that `pkg-config libcouchbase --libs` was not returning proper directory, so I checked the settings in `libcouchbase.pc` and noticed that `libdir` was not properly set. To find out the path to `libcouchbase.pc` I used:

```
brew info libcouchbase
```

and `libcouchbase.pc` was located in `{libcouchbase_install_path}/lib/pkgconfig/libcouchbase.pc`. After modifying value for `libdir` property, the file content looked like this:

```
prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/3.1.1
exec_prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/3.1.1
includedir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/3.1.1/include
libdir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase/3.1.1/lib

Name: libcouchbase 3.1.1
Description: Couchbase client library
Version: 3.1.1
Libs: -L${libdir} -lcouchbase
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Finally, running the php SDK installer worked out fine.